# Finding the weakest precondition using z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to find the weakest precondition given an action and post condition using z3py.

Given the action `N = N + 1` and the post condition `N == 5` the weakest precondition would be N == 4.

Using the Tactic `solve-eqs` this approach works for some post conditions but not others.
When using the post condition `N < 5` I get `[[Not(4 <= N)]]`.

But when using `N == 5` I get `[[]]`, when I would like `N == 4`.

```
N2 = Int('N2') # N after the action
N = Int('N') # N before the action

weakestPreconditionGoal = Goal()

# 'N2 == n + 1' action
# 'N2 == 5' post condition. 
weakestPreconditionGoal.add(N2 == N + 1,  N2 == 5)

t = Tactic('solve-eqs')
wp = t(weakestPreconditionGoal)
print(wp)
```

Is this the best approach find the weakest precondition?

I have tried a several methods but am new to Z3 and can not figure out what approach to take or how to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `solve-eqs` can be used to eliminate equalities. The problem is that we have no control over which equalities will be eliminated. Another option is to use `qe` (quantifier elimination). The example is also available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/BNn2).

```py
N2 = Int('N2') # N after the action
N = Int('N') # N before the action

weakestPreconditionGoal = Goal()

# 'N2 == n + 1' action
# 'N2 == 5' post condition. 
weakestPreconditionGoal.add(Exists([N2], And(N2 == N + 1,  N2 == 5)))

t = Tactic('qe')
wp = t(weakestPreconditionGoal)
print(wp)
```

Another option is to use `solve-eqs`, but "guard" equations that we don't want to eliminate.
We can guard the equations by using an auxiliary predicate `guard`. Here is an example (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/2z2)). Of course, we will have to perform a second pass to eliminate `guard` from the result.

```py
N2 = Int('N2') # N after the action
N = Int('N') # N before the action
guard = Function('guard', BoolSort(), BoolSort())

weakestPreconditionGoal = Goal()

# 'N2 == n + 1' action
# 'N2 == 5' post condition. 
weakestPreconditionGoal.add(N2 == N + 1,  guard(N2 == 5))

t = Tactic('solve-eqs')
wp = t(weakestPreconditionGoal)
print(wp)
```